# HTTP server vs client request in golang

Tags: http, go

The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) says there's a difference between server and client http request, for example, in the case where the body is empty. How do I create a server request to simulate incoming http request for testing purpose?

Edit: I specifically want to create http server request for use during unit test.

Comment: Just do the request: In go or with curl

Comment: In both cases you're working with the same object. It's just how things are handled that is different. For example if you instantiate a request and don't set the method then send that request, it will default to `GET`. However, on the server, when they access the `Method` field, it will never be empty, it will have the method the request used. If you want to some unit test of a server side method, you can just instantiate a request object and pass it into that for testing.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal If I do `req:= http.NewRequest("GET","http://localhost/test","")`, I get a client request. It makes a difference for me because in unit test, when I test for empty body, if  I generate request by NewRequest, empty body will give me `nil`, but if I use curl, empty body is not nil.

Comment: No, you start a server, reqister a handler and then do a request to that server - either using go or curl. Just look at the documentation of the http package.

Comment: Yes but in your example you're not doing much to prep your test object. I might be wrong but I'm pretty confident you could use composite literal syntax to initialize it with all the values you want or just set them after the fact. Now, the advice given by @0x434D53 might be smarter and easier though they serve different purposes so I wouldn't just follow it without considering your needs. If you're starting an http server then sending it an actual request that isn't a unit test. If your request handlers pass the request into other helper methods then it's probably not the right approach here.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Yes, I didn't want to follow the advice by 0x434D53 because I want to write a unit test. I figured this is a common enough scenario, so I'm surprised I couldn't find any reference to it. Do you mind writing up your solution as an answer?

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes and I'll verify what I said is true, assuming it is, I'll make an answer out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed answer. Got a bit side tracked last night. Here's a quick example of making a request object with a non-nil body. One thing to note that I don't think I bothered asking, HTTP GET's don't have a body so you may always get a nil value for that HTTP method. Not positive about that but it would not surprise me if it were the case.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "strings"

func main() {
        reader := strings.NewReader("")
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com", reader)
    fmt.Printf("Body != nil ? %v, value: %s END\n", req.Body != nil, req.Body)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5Fb6b2qgSo

Comment: When it's a server GET request, I get `&{{} {<nil>}}` as the body, not nil, but I can use your idea of `NewReader("")` as well. Thanks!

Comment: @nullgraph awesome! glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you are still looking for an answer here, but Go actually has a package for testing HTTP servers.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/

Its fantastic for testing. You can create both the request and the server through here for testing.